# Continuous function on interval, how do balls look.

Tags: functions, metric-spaces

Consider the metric space $C([a,b]),d_1$.
$$ d_1:\ C([a,b])^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}:\ (f,g) \mapsto \int_a^b|f(x)-g(x)|\ dx$$

- Is this metric space a normed vector space?
- How do open balls look?
  The problem is that we can have arbitrarily long and thin peeks that differ.
- How do closed balls look?
- How can we find the interior and exterior of a subset of $C([a,b])$?

I already, intuitively, think that any subset of $C([a,b])$ has an empty interior and $C([a,b])$ but I've not managed to prove that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result is a normed vector space, but it is not a Banach space because it is not complete. Its completion is $L^1([a,b])$. Frankly it would probably be more fruitful to study $L^1([a,b])$.

One nice thing about normed vector spaces as opposed to metric spaces is that we only have to characterize balls around zero. All other balls are just translations of these. A ball around zero in this space consists of continuous functions such that the integral of their absolute value is bounded by some fixed constant. That's about all that can be said: the actual functions in this ball can be spread out over the interval, they can oscillate extremely fast, they can have extremely narrow peaks, etc.

One problem you seem to be having is that "interior" is relative to the ambient space. So for instance, you can't have $C([a,b])$ having empty interior in itself, because a topological space is always open in itself, even though $C([a,b])$ actually *does* have empty interior in $L^1([a,b])$.